# how to use linux command in c++?

Tags: c++, linux

i am writing a c++ function that will parse .xml file.
i Used system("grep"); type system call to use linux command. now my problem is that i want to select more than one line in given tag. ex.

```
content of .xml file
====================
<state>
 <text> hi this is first li </text>
 <sec> dsfn  sdlkf sfd </sec>
</state>
===================
```

i want to print all content between  and  tag. which and how i can use linux commands.
plz help me....thanks i advance.

Comment: "How do I use grep" belongs on Super User.

Comment: how do I spawn a subprocess and use the output belongs here (C++)

Comment: Search SO for "XML regular expression" to find out why not to use `grep` for parsing XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exec, execve or system calls: demo

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char* args[])
{
    exitcode = system("xsltprox textonly.xslt input.xml > output");
//  exitcode = exec("xsltproc", "textonly.xslt", "input.xml");
    int exitcode;
}
```

Proceed to `fopen` output (or std::fstream reader("output") if you fancy). Note that system is quickly a security hole, so you shouldn't use it in critical apps (like daemons). 
Using exec you could redirect. So you could perhaps open a pipe() from your program, fork(), in the child assign the stdout filedescriptor to the pipe() (see dup2 call) and `exec` in the child.

The parent process can then read the output from the pipe without need for a temp file. 
All of this should be on a zillion tutorials, which I don't have to the time to google for you right now.

---

May I suggest using perl or shell script. If you post an actual example I could show you the code in both shell and c/c++

**Update** here is how to do it with XSLT

textonly.xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[text()]">
            <xsl:if test="text()">
                                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>:
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output demo:

```
o399hee@OWW00837 ~/stacko
$ xsltproc.exe textonly.xslt input.xml

 :
             hi this is first li :
             dsfn  sdlkf sfd :
```

Comment: Note that using libxml2/libxslt you can do the equivalent easily in a few lines of C code

Comment: can we do it in C++ on linux. canu tell ne how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Parsing XML using grep is really not a good idea, you should use some c++ xml parsing library like this one:
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/index.html

Comment: or use libxml2 (with xml++ C++ bindings)

Comment: i just posted a CLI example using xslt

Answer (score 1):

Use the C functions `popen()` and `pclose()`

Here's an example of how to use them:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fstream>

int execShellCommand( const std::string command,
                      std::string& commandOutput )
{
  FILE *fp;
  char charBuf;
  std::ostringstream stdoutBuffer;
  int status;
  std::ostringstream errmsg;

  // Execute command and save its output to stdout
  fp = popen( command.c_str( ), "r" );
  if ( fp == NULL ) {
    // error handling
  } else {
    while ( ( charBuf = fgetc( fp ) ) != EOF ) {
      stdoutBuffer << charBuf;
    }
  }

  // Wait for completion of command and return its exit status
  status = pclose( fp );
  if ( status == -1 ) {
    // error handling
  } else {
    commandOutput = stdoutBuffer.str( );
    return WEXITSTATUS( status ); // convert exit status
  }
}

int main(){
  std::string command = "l | grep lib";
  std::string commandOutput;

  int exitCode = execShellCommand( command, commandOutput);
}
```